# Comment object empty in WP_Comment_Query

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query();
    $comments = $comments_query->query( array( 'number' => 5 ) );
    if ($comments)
    {
        foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
            ?>
            <div class="comment" id="comment-<?php $comment->comment_ID ?>">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <?php get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, 48 ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="text>
                    <a class="author" href="<?php get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID; ?>">
                    <?php get_comment_author( $comment->comment_ID ) ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php strip_tags( substr( apply_filters( 'get_comment_text', $comment->comment_content ), 0, 80 ) ) . '...'; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo 'none.';
    }
?>
```

Here is the resulting HTML of one comment:

```
<div class="comment" id="comment-">
    <div class="avatar">

    </div>
    <div class="text>
        <a class=" author"="" href="">
        <p></p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have comments so the 'none.' is not printed.  However, as you can see, the comment object is empty.  What am I missing/what's going on?

I'm running WP 4.2.2.

Thanks,
Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, something stupid, but even though I was calling the methods, I wasn't `echo`ing the results.